# How to return values to widget form from view in ctools popup?

Tags: views, entities, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I'm writing c**ustom field type and widget** based on it. It allows to create custom entities from node page and add node references on existing nodes.
[image]

There are no problems with custom entities they added via ajax and pass again to widget by `$form_state`. For referencing existing nodes I'm using **entityreference view and ctools popup**. **The problem is deliver back values selected in a view.**

Common way to solve this - is custom submit callback for a view and `ajax_command_replace()` widget html.

But it's not useful in my case, because I'm rebuilding form all the time and only valid data is in `$form_state`.

**Any ideas?**